# How to fix Cross Origin Request Sharing issue in Chromium Portable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, cors, chromium-portable

I am trying to fix CORS issue in Chromium Portable. Added

```
 --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security
```

Works for the older versions but not for the latest one. Will not be able to modify anything on the server side and also cannot use `jsonp`.

The error I am getting in the console is :

```
jquery.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://website/heaarc/rest/HaAccess/hello. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'file://' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

Is there any other way to fix this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this by adding an updated flag for chromium.

The flag is:

```
-disable-web-security -user-data-dir
```

Also to prevent any warning messages and popups, I used this:

```
-test-type
```